# iOS frameworks. Template functions with same name, linker picks up wrong function?

Tags: c++, xcode, ios-frameworks

I've got a simple iOS app with two frameworks. Each framework have a public function which returns a specific value from private template function.
When app call public functions from frameworks - I expect to get those different specific values, but each framework calls the same template function from the first embedded framework!

```
framework01
    testFramework01.h
        int framework01_Func();               // public function, calls private template function "func"
    common.h
        template<typename T> int func(T & data)   // private template function, returns "11"
```

```
framework02
    testFramework02.h
        int framework02_Func();               // public function, calls private template function "func"
    common.h
        template<typename T> int func(T & data)   // private template function, returns "22"
```

```
App
    int n1 = framework01_Func();        // expecting to get "11", got "11"
    int n2 = framework02_Func();        // expecting to get "22", but got "11"
```

When I remove "template" state from private functions - everything starts working as expected.

Could anyone explain me - why each framework can't use its own private function?
Is there any way to preserve own functions in each frameworks (any linker flag or something)?

As a bonus - each framework have a global variable with same name, and there's no "multiple symbols" error when building the app, so framework embedding is not the same as static linking
There's no such issues in windows and DLLs (data is stored in own address space). Do iOS frameworks works different?

Source project is here: https://github.com/iamlosthere/iOSFrameworksWithSameFunctionName

Thanks.

Comment: This is undefined behavior, violation of the One Definition Rule, no diagnostic required. You can only have ***one*** definition of a given template function. It doesn't matter that some translation units see one version, and others see a different version. This is undefined behavior.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik  `It doesn't matter that some translation units see one version, and others see a different version.` Yes. But this is a different projects, not related to each other. They are builded to separate binaries. And  dynamically loaded by obj-c runtime. So I expect to have both of the functions...